# symfony/vuejs authentification IS REQUIRED

Tags: authentication, security, apache2, symfony4, web-application-firewall

I have a Symfony/Vue.js app, and I've hosted each one in a subdomain using Apache2. However, when I try to authenticate, I can't proceed, and I receive a 401 error indicating that full authentication is required. Strangely, in my local environment, I am able to authenticate, and individuals from other countries can also authenticate using the same email and password
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugTA6.png)

"I'm trying to host my app online, but I'm encountering issues. Both Symfony and Vue.js work perfectly fine in my local environment, but when I try to host them online, I'm facing authentication problems. I'm unsure about the exact cause of the issue. Additionally, I'm puzzled as to why I can't authenticate from other countries. Any insights or sugges[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgCNS.png)tions on resolving these problems would be greatly appreciated